# Перемещение ползунка прогресс-бара

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Ползунок прогресс-бара при нажатии кнопки "далее" перемещается на 20% вправо, и сумма скидки увеличивается на 2000 руб, переходит ко второму вопросу (этому блоку со списком ответов присваивается display: none; следующему - display: block)  Нужно сделать так, чтобы это происходило при условии, что выбран ответ. Мой вариант не работает.

```
<div class="answers" id="answers1">
 <ul>
   <li>Частный дом</li>
   <li>Дача</li>
   <li>Производство</li>
   <li>Отель/гостиница</li>
   <li>Другое</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
<div class="sale-line">
 <div class="main-line">
   <div class="progress-line" id="progress-line">
   <span class="salesum">0</span> руб
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

 <a href="#" class="next-btn big-link">Дальше</a>

<style>
  .septik-select .sale-line .main-line {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #167c80;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 182px; }

.septik-select .sale-line .main-line .progress-line {
  position: absolute;
  top: -28px;
  left: 0%;
  width: 20%;
  z-index: 100;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #167c80;
  text-align: center; 
</style>

  $(document).ready(function(){
    var im = 0
        $('.septik-select .answers ul li').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        im=1;
        }); 
    var it = 0  
        $('.septik-select .next-btn').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
            it = it+2000;
            $('.septik-select .salesum').html(it);

            if (im=1 ){
            $('.septik-select .progress-line').animate({'left':'+=20%'})
                im=0;
                ;}
        }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.next-btn').click(function() {
   if($('.radio-ex').is(':checked')) { alert("it's checked"); }
});
```

```css
 .septik-select .sale-line .main-line {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #167c80;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 182px; }

.septik-select .sale-line .main-line .progress-line {
  position: absolute;
  top: -28px;
  left: 0%;
  width: 20%;
  z-index: 100;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #167c80;
  text-align: center;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="answers" id="answers1">
  <input type="radio" class="radio-ex" name="example">
  <label>Частный дом</label>
  <input type="radio" class="radio-ex" name="example">
  <label>Дача</label>
  <input type="radio" class="radio-ex" name="example">
  <label>Производство</label>
 </div>
<div class="sale-line">
 <div class="main-line">
   <div class="progress-line" id="progress-line">
   <span class="salesum">0</span> руб
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

 <a href="#" class="next-btn big-link">Дальше</a>
```

Comment: jQuery - зло :)